# New Seagate 2TB hard drive not recognized in Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Added a new Seagate 2TB SATA internal drive to my Gigabyte Z68 Motherboard system with two current drives, a 2TB SATA used as `C:` drive, and an old 200GB drive used for miscellaneous backup.

The BIOS sees the drive configured as a slave to the `C:` drive, but file directory in Windows 10 does not see it. It does recognize the old 200GB partitions as `E:` and `F:`, skipping a `D:` drive altogether.

I switched the power and SATA cables between the new drive and the 200GB drive and Windows still saw the old one and not the new one. Any suggestions before I return the drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If motherboard does recognize the Disk, you should go to Disk Management, and check if the Disk is Listed there, if it is, just create a Partition for It, if not check your BIOS Settings.

Disk Management Can be Found

1. Computer->Right Click->Manage->Disk Management
2. CMD/RUN/Start Search->diskmgmt.msc